# Overwrite <Host> tag when I run Tomcat from eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat, server.xml

I want to serve images from an external folder outside webapps. In order to do this I have to add `<context>` tag inside `<host>` in server.xml

```
<Context  docBase="c:\project\upload\images"   path="/images" />
```

to make

```
<img src="/images/img_1.jpg" />
```

but when I run tomcat from eclipse, `<host>...</host>` is overwritten and my configuration line is removed.

I am using tomcat 8.

Comment: a better way would be to have a servlet that serves these external files